# How to dynamically move Vector Features in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Based from an example given here: http://openlayers.org/en/vector-api/examples/dynamic-data.html?q=dynamic

Instead of using circle:

```
var imageStyle = new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 5,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'yellow'}),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'red', width: 1})
});
```

I want to use Vector Feature (Marker) as the object which is moving instead of using that yellow circle.

An example of using a feature vector is found here:

[how to add markers with OpenLayers 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315801/how-to-add-markers-with-openlayers-3)

Sorry, just a beginner in OpenLayers 3. Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made you [a basic example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2VNqoz?p=preview).

The idea is: You move an Overlay through a path using an interval to change its position like:

```
//fire the animation
map.once('postcompose', function(event) {
    interval = setInterval(animation, 500);
});

var i = 0, interval;
var animation = function(){

    if(i == path.length){
        i = 0;
    }

    marker.setPosition(path[i]);
    i++;
};
```